# self class alloc equivalent in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Model class written in Objective-C, it's suppose to be inherit by sub-classes. There's a method:

```
- (id)deepcopy {
    id newModel = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    newModel.id = self.id;
    // do something
    return newModel;
}
```

sub-classes should override it with something like:

```
- (id)deepcopy {
    id newModel = [super deepcopy];
    // something else
    return newModel;
}
```

The key is **[[[self class] alloc] init]**, which will instance an object based on the actual class. Recently I try to upgrade this project to Swift, but could not find a way to do the same thing in Swift.

How can I do that?

Comment: Good question ! Also useful for inheriting singleton sharedInstance style getters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `dynamicType`:

```
func deepcopy() -> Self {
    let newModel = self.dynamicType.init()
    return newModel
}
```

**Update** As for Swift 3, this seems to work:

```
func deepcopy() -> Self {
    let newModel = type(of: self).init()
    return newModel
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I tried this early, but it reported an error, I thought it's incorrect. Now I found out it's due to other reason.

Comment: When trying to use this on a subclass of `UIViewController`, I get the following error: `Type 'MyViewController.Type' has no member 'init'` Any idea what the issue there is? I'm writing Swift 3.

Comment: @Banana : plz help me regarding same issue

Comment: @Banana make required initializer.